# Cookies ignored on Apache/Magento installation

Tags: apache, cookies, magento

I'm running a Magento based website store on Linux/Apache.

In order that user logins are maintained, I've set my cookie lifetime to be close to two years.  The cookies are sent out with the right times, I can see them in my browsers.  When I visit the site from a previously logged-in browser after about a day, the user is logged out.  I can still see the cookies, with their extended life, present in the browser.

Where should I start looking to get to the bottom of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the value of PHP's session.gc_maxlifetime parameter? Regardless of the life that Magento allows, this lifetime setting will still kill cookies after a little while. In your .htaccess file in the magento directory, add this:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 31536000
```

That may solve the problem.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Good idea.  I found that this value was quite small (3600) in my php.ini.  I changed it to the value you suggested - a year.  Found that I'm still logged out this morning, though.  Something else must be afoot.

Comment: By chance is the computer set to expire cookies or use some other type of privacy option?

Comment: Your first answer was the right one.  Once I changed the value in php.in and *restarted Apache* (:smack:), it's behaving appropriately.  Many thanks.